# Pattern Match on String in Scala

Tags: scala, haskell

How can I pattern match on a String in Scala:

```
scala> "55" match {
     | case x :: _ => x
     | }
<console>:9: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.::[B]
 required: String
              case x :: _ => x
                     ^
```

In Haskell a `String` is a List of Char `[Char]`:

```
Prelude> :i String
type String = [Char]    -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
```

So it supports pattern matching on a `String`.

How can I do this in Scala?

Comment: I was going to add an answer, but that duplicate question covers it well

Comment: thank you for pointing out this dupe. My mistake (but I'm glad I learned from extempore's answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use extractors. Scala allows you to build your own deconstruction functions, the most `SeqLike` Collections offer `+:` it works just like `::` for `List`, unfortunately `String` doesn't have this operator for deconstruction, only for construction.

But you can define your own extractor for `String` like this:

```
object %:: {
    def unapply(xs: String): Option[(Char, String)] =
      if (xs.isEmpty) None
      else Some((xs.head, xs.tail))
  }
```

Usage:

```
scala> val x %:: xs = "555"
x: Char = 5
xs: String = 55
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but a set of suggestions

Comment: I've added an implementation of the extractor. I think now this should qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply convert it into a list:

```
"55".toList
```